# Representatives in the quotient of a lower central series of a free group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Let $F$ be a free group of letters $\{x_1,...,x_m\}$ and define $$F_1:=F$$
$$F_k:=[F_{k-1},F]$$
According to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317048/third-quotient-of-the-lower-central-series), $F_2/F_3$ and $F_3/F_4$ are generated by representatives given by basic commutators in $F_2$ and $F_3$ respectively, i.e. $[x_i,x_j]$ and $[[x_i,x_j],x_k]$.

> Is $F_k/F_{k+1}$ generated by basic commutators in $F_k$ ?

By definition any element can be written as a product of commutators which are not necessarily the basic commutators.

If a proof is too technical I would accept an answer stating the result and possibly a source where one can look for the proof itself.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. The proofs are indeed technical. They can be found in Marshall Hall's textbook on group theory - although coincidentally the theory of basic commutators is due to Philp Hall.

Comment: @Derek Thank you. You could post this comment as an answer so that I accept and we can close this question.